# get device token without enter to the function didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Tags: ios, push-notification, devicetoken

I have in the settings page a button to let the user enable or disable the push notification.

If the user doesn't allow to receive push notification the first time he launch the application, how can I get the Device Token if the user turn on the notification setting later in setting page?

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully, you can't get the device token, if the APNS is disabled . You can manually check that is it disabled and then enable it back then the delegate method gets called .

Comment: @Houssam You must call didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible , when user authenticate the `allow permission` and run your project , it automatically  call the method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` else it call the `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
(NSData *)deviceToken {

NSString* deviceTokene = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] ;



NSLog(@"%@",deviceTokene);


}
```

this is the `coding` to enable the `APNS` in Viewcontroller

```
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

if you want to disable the `APNS` in inside the VC

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: Thanks man, but my qyestion how can I call this function from a view controller?

Comment: have a  happy day my friend

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, you can't get the device token unless the user allows you to, and once user allows it, you have to retrieve device token from the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` call back.

If the user denied your push notification request for the first time, until the user enable push notification service for you app in `Setting.app->Privacy`, you can't get the token.

So you should check

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]`

every time user changes the setting of notifications in you App,
if the result is that notification is not enabled, you should guide the user to change the notification setting in `Setting.app->Privacy`;
if the result is that notification is enabled, you use this code to retrieve the token:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert]
```

this will trigger the `-didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` callback.

Comment: thanks man so in the settings view controller how can I call the function didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?

Comment: @HoussamHammoud is your setting view controller part of your app, or is it in the system setting app?